# Use Python to covert 400,000 latitude & longitudes to zip code

Tags: python, geocoding, latitude-longitude, geopy, zipcode

I have 400,000 cases with latitudes and longitudes. I want to convert these to zip codes. The code below works...

```
import geopy

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent='my-application')

def get_zipcode(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field):
    location = geolocator.reverse((df[lat_field], df[lon_field]))
    if 'address' in location.raw.keys():
      if 'postcode' in location.raw['address'].keys():
        return location.raw['address']['postcode']
    else:
      None
```

But only on smaller batches, but it takes a while, like 15 minutes for 2,000 cases.

```
dfbatch1['pickup_zip'] = dfbatch1.apply(get_zipcode, axis=1, geolocator=geolocator, lat_field='pickup_latitude', lon_field='pickup_longitude')
```

What would be the best way to convert all of my latitudes & longitudes to zip codes?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how many keys might be available in location.raw, but for a start, I would get rid of testing if the keys exist - just assume it does and put it in a try except. Also, where do you expect your latitude and longitude to be? all over the world or just one country? Maybe you could try to set the country_bias (don't know if it makes anything faster though)? I guess the problem is more the call to some server that contains the data.

Comment: Please honour [Nominatim's Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). It says explicitly: "No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second)" and under unacceptable use it includes Systematic queries: "This includes reverse queries in a grid, searching for complete lists of postcodes, towns etc. and downloading all POIs in an area. If you need complete sets of data, get it from the OSM planet or an extract.". **I assume that you are throttled down because of too many requests.**

Comment: You could install your own instance of Nomatim - that would probably make things faster. Source: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/

Comment: `threading` or `multiprocessing` to run requests in parallel. But see @Thomas comment on fair usage too !

Comment: I'm not sure you need a geocoding service for this: if you're just trying to convert lat/lon pairs to zipcodes, you could do this yourself using a free zipcode dataset (like [this one](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24)) and a little work with `geopandas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: not a GIS expert here!

It seems like this would be pretty easy using [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) and a source of zip code polygons (noting, of course, that zip codes are [not, in fact, polygons](https://manifold.net/doc/mfd9/zip_codes_are_not_areas.htm)):

For example, if I have a point data source with `(lat, lon)` pairs in a file `points.geojson`, I could do something like this:

```
import geopandas

points = geopandas.read_file('points.geojson')
zipcodes = geopandas.read_file("zip_poly.gdb")
zip_points = points.sjoin(zipcodes, how='left', )
```

The default behavior of `sjoin` is to perform an `intersects` query, which is what we want.

That gives me a geodataframe that maps coordinates (in the `.geometry` attribute) to zip codes (in the `.ZIP_CODE` attribute). I used [this source](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24) for zip code data.

For example, given a point:

```
>>> points.query('NAME == "Boston"').geometry
1436    POINT (-71.05671 42.35959)
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

I now know its zip code:

```
>>> zip_points.query('NAME=="Boston"').ZIP_CODE
1436    02109
Name: ZIP_CODE, dtype: object
```

I tested this using a data source with about 4000 points; I don't have handy anything approaching your 400000 point data source.

Comment: I am a GIS Developer and would consider this approach as well.